# is there a shortcut in eclipse for generating resources (constructors , get/set .....)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

currently in  eclipse if i want to generate a constructor or getters/setters i 
go the class name **right click on that ->source->access the right Generation option**

[image: eclipse]

while in the android studio we have a convenient and fast shortcut to do that 
i just need to press `CMD+N` anywhere in the page to open the generate dialog

[image: android studio]

is there an eclipse shortcut available that is equivalent to that ?

Comment: just type `Alt+s ` then type `c` for `constructor`, `r` for `set/get` `s` for `toString` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Press `Alt+s` then type `c` for `constructor`, `r` for `set/get` `s` for
>   `toString`etc..

Comment: thanks, i know that it is not exactly the same as i wanted but opening the source menu using the short cut is the fastest way; in case of mac you will need to press alt + cmd + s to enable the menu, the c,r,s that you mentioned after that doesn't work. i will add this as a separate answer for anyway one looking for the MAC short cut

Answer (score 4):

You can go to `Windows -> Preferences  -> General -> Keys` to map this action to a shortcut of choice.

This is how to do it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one by default, but if you wish you can modify the mappings and add a shortcut. You can do this by going to `window->preferences->general->keys`

Answer (score 2):

1. Go in `window -> preferences -> general -> keys`
2. Type **generate** in the search bar.
3. Find **Generate Getters and Setters**
4. Click on the `binding` field and hit your custom shortcut (here : Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys` or you can take the list of shortcut in this site [25 Eclipse Shortcut Keys](http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/25-eclipse-shortcut-keys-for-code-editing)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the quick fix : **Ctrl + 1**.

When you have an error, it allows you to resolve this error. and when the cursor is on a variable, it allows you to generate getter and setter.

[image]

If you want an empty construtor, just type **Ctrl + space** somewhere in your class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

But google shows a number of pages on how to do it, e.g. https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F

A lateral solution, but you may be interested to check out [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) (I don't use it myself at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember ,alt + insert do this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by  @Rustam put me on the right path.

but since his answer is based on windows version of eclipse and I am using mac i was unable to confirm it .

i added this answer to provide additional data for any one using the MAC version of eclipse

**ALT + CMD + S** will bring the **source menu** after that you can select the correct generation option